# Отображение бейджа с новыми объектами Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, backend

У меня есть модель **Отзывы** и архитектура клиент-сервер, когда количество отзывов увеличивается нужно на клиенте получать информацию для бейджа (+3 новых отзыва), при открытии вкладки это количество должно обнуляться. Понятия не имею как это реализовать и где найти что-то подобное, буду благодарен за любую подсказку[image: Вот что то на подобии этого]